# How to change background color in REPL in Eclipse's Scala plugin?

Tags: eclipse, scala, read-eval-print-loop

How to change background color in REPL in Eclipse's Scala plugin? My Scala syntax coloring scheme is configured to work with a dark background and is currently unusable with the REPL's white background. Alternatively, I could also work with syntactic coloring disabled in REPL (so that everything would just get printed in black), but I don't know if it's possible to configure the plugin in such way.

Answer (score 1):

Click the `window` menu and then choose the `preferences` menu item to open the `preferences` dialog.

In the left panel, navigate to `General`/`Appearance`/`Colors and Fonts`.

In the right panel, expand the `Scala` node, select the `Interpreter background color`, press the `Edit` button, choose the desired color, press `ok`, and finally the `Apply` button.

If the change isn't reflected, **restart** eclipse. At least for the 4.7.0 version **the restart is necessary**.